# Page layout: Whole page table layout or page with frame

Tags: tables, framed, ltxtable

I have to recreate a horrible page layout from a WYSIWIG template, so that I can at least use LaTeX. The page layout shall be used in a larger document, so no individual documentstyle shall be used. The template is shown here:

[image]

The key features are:

- A heading ("Abstract")
- A couple of organizational informations (first 5 table rows)
- Rest of the table is running text
- The running text cell can span up to 2 pages
- The cells of the running text shall span until the bottom of the page unaffected by the actual amount of text

  - If running text only fills one page, you have the first 5 rows and the running text cell until the bottom of the first page
  - If running text is 2 pages long, page 2 basically has a frame around the whole page

I don't really have an idea where to start. I could use [`ltxtable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable?lang=de) but do not know how to
 - get a page break within the running text cell and
 - stretch the border to the bottom of the page.

Any suggestions? Is a framed page maybe the better solution?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{ltxtable}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Abstract}

\begin{filecontents}{testtable.tex}
\begin{longtable}{lX}
\toprule
Info1:  & Data1  \\
\midrule
Info2:  & Long Data2  \\
\midrule
Info3:  & Data3  \\
\midrule
Info4:  & Data4  \\
\midrule
Info5:  & Data5  \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
% Actual text:
\multicolumn{2}{X}{\blindtext[5]}       \\
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\LTXtable{\linewidth}{testtable.tex}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```